# Why jQuery does not execute Javascript if only a part of received HTML is inserted into DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following file which will be loaded through AJAX:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>I  need this in AJAX and the following scripts too</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('I am executed');
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="some_included_script.js"></script>
 </div>

<div>I do not need this in AJAX</div>
```

If I load it the following way:

```
  $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: "GET",
          cache: false,
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(data) {
              $('#my_big_container').html(data);
         }
     });
```

then all the scripts get executed and also some_included_script.js gets requested from server and executed. No problems.

But if I need just the part inside of "container" and try the following code:

```
  $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: "GET",
          cache: false,
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(data) {
              $('#my_big_container').html(
                    $(data).filter('#container').html()
              );
         }
     });
```

then none of the scripts get executed and there is also no request for some_included_script.js (although the plain HTML contents of "container" get inserted into 'my_big_container' correctly).

Why the scripts get executed when I use entire 'data' but not when I filter just a part of it?

How can I load just a part of received data and get inner scripts executed automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works:

Instead of this:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#my_big_container').html(
        $(data).filter('#container').html()
    );
}
```

Try this:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#my_big_container').html(
        $("<div>").html(data).find('#container')
    );
}
```